# Tracking multiple hashtags using twitter stream API

Tags: twitter

When I access (w/ proper credentials):

https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?lang=en&track=#help'

I get what I want: an unending stream of tweets with the #help hashtag.

However,

https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?lang=en&track=#help,#perl

yields the error

Illegal character in fragment at index 70: 
https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?lang=en&track=#help,#perl

which appears to be the '#' in '#perl'. How to fix?

For reference, this works fine:

https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?lang=en&track=perl,#help

while this does not:

https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?lang=en&track=perl,#help,#ruby

Is there a rule re not tracking more than one hashtag, or am I doing 
something more fundamentally wrong? Should I track '#hashtag' by just 
tracking 'hashtag'?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? According to this: dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track you mustn't include # in the track command. So

Comment: Replacing the # with %23 also works, but post your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: I think you should add your comment as the answer, as it's more accurate and good SO karma.

Comment: My comment, while technically correct, is stupid :) I don't think %23 actually does anything. Please, you go ahead and I'll approve your answer, Alphonse... ;) As an interesting note, curl actually sends the '#' to the server, whereas Firefox more correctly does not. The # is a client-side direction, not a server-side one (at least in the original HTML spec)

Answer (score 0):

```
['term1,term2']
```

But what about the hashtags?  This link says not to use them:  https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track

We can remove the apostrophes and spaces (in python) with

```
upgrades_str = re.sub('[\' \[\]]', '', upgrades_str)
upgrades_str = '[\''+format(upgrades_str)+'\']'
```